# Defining a function that detects square matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, homework

> Define a function g, which receives a list and returns True if that list represents a square array, and False otherwise.

I only can use `Table`, `Map`, and `Apply`.

Examples:

```
g[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}] deverá retornar True
g[{{1,2,3},{4},{7,8}}] deverá retornar False
g[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}] deverá retornar False
g[{{1,2},1+x}] deverá retornar False
```

This is my code:

```
gl = 
  Function[w,
    Apply[
      And, 
      Table[If[w[[i]] == Length[w], True, False], {i, 1, Length[w]}]]]`
```

or

```
g = 
  Function[w,
    Apply[And, Map[Function[x, If[x == Length[x], True, False]], w]]]
```

Comment: 1) Statements like `If[test, True, False]` is always equal to simply `test`: Remember that `If` checks whether `test == True`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Strictly speaking, your statement is not true. If `test` does not evaluate to `True` or `False`, then `If` remains unevaluated and is *not* equivalent to `test` (they are different expressions).

Comment: 2) When your test is `w[[i]] == Length[w]` or `x == Length[x]`, you are asking whether the i'th row of `w` (generally a vector if `w` is a list of `Depth` 2 like in all the examples) is equal to the number of rows in `w`. What you want is to check that the number of columns is equal to the number of rows, right? Then `Length[w[[i]]]` will give you the number of columns in row i.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, of course, I forgot about that in this context *sigh*. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer np :)

Comment: You can simply construct a test with Dimensions

Comment: Use [`SquareMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareMatrixQ.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that for a $ n \times 1$ matrix, Dimensions may b a singleton so

```
g = If[MatrixQ[#] && Length[Dimensions[#]] == 2 && 
    Dimensions[#][[1]] == Dimensions[#][[2]], True, False] &
```

Now if

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
g[l]
```

gives true and false for the other cases

Comment: The OP states "I only can use Table, Map, Apply..." though.

Comment: True but the answer seems to satisfy  Paulo Rodrigues

Comment: `g[{{1, 2}, {3, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}}]` returns `True` which seems wrong.

Comment: Simon Woods, your Matrix is ambiguous and for Mathematica Dimensions[{{1, 2}, {3, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}}] si {2, 2}.

Comment: But `{{1, 2}, {3, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}} // MatrixQ` returns `False`, as does `ArrayQ`. So at least as far as *Mathematica* is concerned, `Dimensions` are not the only thing to take into account.

Comment: Michael E2 I have edited the answer to take in account your comment

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Looking at the [`MatrixQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixQ.html) docs one sees that `MatrixQ` is defined to check for lists in the matrix so a one liner solution including that might be `Differences@Dimensions@# == {0} && AllTrue[#, FreeQ[#, _List, 1] &] &`.